# Other than the two testaments, are there any texts that take place in the same universe?

Tags: canonicity, literary-genre

Other than the two testaments, are there any other texts/works that [canonically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_(fiction)) take place in the same [fictional universe/continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictional_universe)?

Comment: The question in the Title is different from the question in the Body. The answers will be quite different ("same? yes" and "canonical? no"). Pick one and change the other to agree with it.

Comment: Also, this isn't the correct site for this question. Questions should be about specific pieces of biblical text, not general ideas.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: I don’t mean canonical in the sense normally used here, but in the sense that I linked to.

Comment: _associated with works of fantasy and science fiction._ is inappropriate.

Comment: The question could certainly be improved but please note that [literary genre](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literary-genre) is an acceptable topic here even if the OP did not tag it as such. I have added the tag now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give a quick answer before the OP is closed, because I think it raises a hermeneutical question dealing the the apocrypha, which is an acceptable topic here. The answer is yes, several of the [apocrypha and pseudepigrapha](http://www.pseudepigrapha.com/) occupy the same "fictional universe" as the OT and NT (although I don't like this term in the context of a group that takes the Bible very seriously). I refer the reader to the linked site above.

Some that deserve special mention:

- The Books of the Maccabees
- The Book of Jubilees
- The Book of Enoch

The above are all intertestamental books written between the time of the Exile and the advent of Jesus. The Books of the Maccabees are accepted by Catholics and Orthodox churches but considered apocryphal by Protestants and Jews. All of the OT Apocrypha fall into the OP's category. I singled out Maccabees for its style, which closely resembles other OT histories.

In the New Testament Age there are both heretical and proto-orthodox works that fit the description. The Apocalypse of Peter and the Shepherd of Hermas are two examples that were actually included in some early versions the NT. See also the Acts of Thomas, the Acts of Paul and Thecla and other apocryphal books in the "acts" genre, and various Gnostic gospels.

Comment: I agree that this questions should have been closed, but I do not agree with the down vote this helpful answer received.  I have upvoted to balance things somewhat.  Many thanks for being helpful.

Comment: I have a copy of a large series of documents loosely described as "The Old Testament Pseudepigrapha" containing works such as The Apocalypse of Abraham, The Apocalypse of Adam, Letters of Aristeas, 2 Baruch, 3 Baruch, 4 Baruch, and dozens more.  There were lots of people writing stuff in this time.  Then there are a large series of documents that are loosely called, the NT pseudepigrapha, etc.  However, I am sure you would be aware of most of these.

Comment: The key thing to note is that most of the apocryphal texts contradict the canon (and often each other), and so can't be considered in-universe.

Comment: The ones that I specifically mentioned above are less contradictory to the canonical OT/NT than many others. I do consider them to be in the same universe in terms of literary genre.